# delete object property with row count appended

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use `delete` and I have tried to append a row count on there. 
I have realised you can not do this after Googleing the error.
`delete vm.eicr.observation.observationCode + row.toString();`

`var row = table.rows[i];` when I add the number on `observationCode1` it all works well.

I have tried :`var t = vm.eicr.observation.observationCode + row.toString();`
 but the `delete` wants a property i.e `delete t.propname + row.toString();` as this brings me back to square one.

How can I do this `delete vm.eicr.observation.observationCode + row.toString();`

This is my part of my code:

```
for (var i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
                var row = table.rows[i];
                var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
                if (null != chkbox && true === chkbox.checked) {
                    var celllength = row.cells.length;
                    var cell;
                    for (var j = 1; j < celllength; j++) {
                        cell = row.cells[j];
                        console.log(cell);
                        var t = vm.eicr.observation.observationCode + row.toString();
                        delete vm.eicr.observation.observationCode + row.toString();
                    }                       
                    table.deleteRow(i);
                    rowCount--;
                    i--;
                } else {
                    toastr.error("Please select the Delete checkbox", "ERROR");
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding of the code above you can use square bracket notation []. The following code should work:

```
delete vm.eicr.observation['observationCode' + row.toString()];
```

I hope I have understood the problem correctly.